# Why is not 'python' recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file?

Tags: python

So I'm new so forgive me for my mistakes but I'm trying to run my code in Atom and when I do so it says

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.054s]
```

Please help as I have spent about 3 hours looking for help and the most I have gotten was just "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"

Comment: It seems python is not in your path. You are running on Windows? How did you install python? Try `python3` and `py` to see if they work. Have you logged off/on since install? Depending on how you installed, that may help get a new PATH variable for you.

Comment: I am using windows 10 64-bit. I installed python directly from python.org. I have tried Python 3.9.0 and 3.7.6 but neither has worked. Atom doesn't seem to pick up py so that is most likely my problem but I'm not sure how to find it inside of Atom. I have logged off and then re-logged since the install.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add python to the environment path variables.

1. You need to go and find your python path.
2. Copy the path and then go to `this pc`
3. Right-click and select properties
4. Click Advanced system settings from the left
5. Make sure you're on the advanced tab and click the environment variables
6. Find something named `Path` and then double click on it
7. Click `new` and then add the path to the environment variables

For more clarity check:-
https://hackanons.com/2018/06/how-to-add-python-path-environment-variable-in-windows-8-10.html

Also check:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nXvBrK2wxWc

and
https://appuals.com/fix-python-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/

Comment: this actually worked thank you so much! I can finally rest now knowing I can run something.

Comment: Then please upvote my answer and mark it as solved so that it is marked as answered on stack overflow(it's a rule.)